# Leetcode Q. 1528. Shuffle String

Tags: swift, algorithm, dictionary, hashmap

Given a string s and an integer array indices of the same length.

The string s will be shuffled such that the character at the ith position moves to indices[i] in the shuffled string.

Return the shuffled string.

Input: s = "codeleet", indices = [4,5,6,7,0,2,1,3]
Output: "leetcode"

[image]

Explanation: As shown, "codeleet" becomes "leetcode" after shuffling.

```
class Solution {
    func restoreString(_ s: String, _ indices: [Int]) -> String {
        
      //convert the string into a hash map where all keys are Ints and the values are the Strings.
    //Run a for loop through the dictionary and return the key of the value in indices.
    //time complexity: O(n)
    //Space complexity: O(n)
    
        
        var newString = s.map{ String($0) }
        var y = ""
        var count = 0
        var dict = [Int:String]()
        var z = 0
        
        while count < newString.count {
            dict[count] = newString[count]
            count += 1
        }
        
        while z < indices.count {
            y.append(dict[indices[z]]!)
            z += 1
        }
        print(dict)
        
        return y
    }
}
```

The first while loop creates a dictionary and the second while loop finds the values with matching keys and appends into a string. My issue is that my code is outputting two characters in the wrong location.

```
Input: "codeleet"
[4,5,6,7,0,2,1,3]

Output: "leetcdoe"
```

Can you please help me explain what I'm missing here.

Comment: What does Shuffling (a) String mean?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the task. The character a position i should be put into the position indices[i]. You are doing it the other way around. I suggest to have a look at the diagram in https://leetcode.com/problems/shuffle-string/ again.

Comment: you return y but print dict. is it correct?

Comment: That is very simple. Just split string into array characters then insert that array characters to new array with indices.

Comment: kindly mark as accepted below answer if its working and you understand as well thanks

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib I wanted to view where i was going wrong, so i printed the dictionary.

Comment: @MartinR I went the wrong direction by not mapping correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a one to one hashing not a index based hashing which you were doing in above code below is the updated correct version of your code:-

```
class Solution {
    func restoreString(_ s: String, _ indices: [Int]) -> String {
       var newString = s.map{ String($0) }
        var y = ""
        var count = 0
        var dict = [Int:String]()
        var z = 0
        
        while count < newString.count {
            dict[indices[count]] = newString[count]
            count += 1
        }
        
        while z < indices.count {
        y.append(dict[z]!)
            z += 1
        }
        print(dict)
        
        return y
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Solution {
public String restoreString(String s, int[] indices) {
    String s1="";
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
            if(i==indices[j]){
                s1=s1+s.charAt(j);
            }
        }
    }return s1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func restoreString(_ s: String, _ indices: [Int]) -> String {
    var letters = [String]()
    var result = ""
    
    s.forEach{
        letters.append(String($0))
    }
    
    for (index,value) in s.enumerated(){
        letters[indices[index]] = value.description
    }
    
    result = letters.reduce("", +)
  
    return result }
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may solve the problem at hand, more explanation is necessary to help future users of the site understand how to apply this solution to their situation.

Answer (score -1):

```
// MARK : LeetCode #1528. Shuffle String--#AppCodeZip

func restoreString(_ s: String, _ indices: [Int]) -> String {
var arrText = Array(s)
var result = String()
var count = 0

while count <= arrText.count - 1 {
    for i in 0...arrText.count - 1 {
        if indices[i] == count {
            result += String(arrText[i])
        }
    }
    count += 1
}
return result
}
```